# Update the password in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am novice to php-mysql ...please help me to rectify the syntax error
the error is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/u831097172/public_html/php/update.php on line 13
```

line 13:

```
UPDATE $tbl_name SET password= '$password' WHERE email='$email';
```

Comment: Is that the whole line?

Comment: You claim to be a novice, and as such you should really know about SQL-injection: a very common security hole. Your example, and worse so, the examples in the answers below, suffer from potential SQL-injection-holes. Read up on them here, before releasing any of this code: http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 3):

maybe you mean something like

```
$query = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET password = '$password' WHERE email='$email'";
```

remeber to add slashes to your $password and $email variable to avoid sql-injection

Answer (score 1):

I think you should learn directly with statements:

```
$mysqliConnection = new mysqli($SERVER, $USER, $PW, $TABLE);
$stmt = mysqliConnection->prepare("UPDATE ? SET password = ? WHERE email = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $tbl_name, $password, $email);
$stmt->execute();
```

Here's the doc :) https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

Are the variables filled?

Maybe its better you make

```
$query = "UPDATE " . $tbl_name . " SET password='" . $password . "'
          WHERE email='" . $email . "'";
```

And then you can check simple if you print the String out. There you can see if your variables are filled:

```
print_r($query);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have your variable $tbl_name not in quotes $tbl_name has to be '$tbl_name'

Comment: A - reputation without a comment?

Comment: Because there is no need for *quotes* in this particular example. Why would you want to put table name inside `'` or `"` ?

Comment: Oh yeah i misread the query im sorry